# How to export variable inside a function to another module

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to generate an array and store the value inside a variable and export that variable in a way that i can acess it anywhere i want in my application.

```
const generateNewArray = () => {

  var numberOfArrayItems = 40;
  var currentArray = Array.from({ length: numberOfArrayItems }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 1);

  return currentArray;
}


export { generateNewArray }
```

But, until right now i could only export the function. And when i invoke "generateNewArray" i get the function body as answer, and when i invoke "generateNewArray()" i get another random array, different from the original.

How can i acess the "currentArray" variable from anywhere in my application?

Thanks!

Comment: the value returned from this function will be different everytime you call it because you geta random number so it's normal no ?

Comment: Yep! Thats correct, i want to generate a random array in every function invoke but i would like to store the value in a variable that i can acess anywhere i want. And if i invoke that function, the value of the variable will change.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a local variable, set its value, and then export the variable itself:

```js
const generateNewArray = () => {

  var numberOfArrayItems = 40;
  var currentArray = Array.from({ length: numberOfArrayItems }, 
    () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 1);
  
  return currentArray;
}

const myRandomArray = generateNewArray();
export { myRandomArray }
```

Comment: Hey Christian, thanks for the answer! But i would like that the variable is the same anywhere in the application, but when i invoke the function the value of the variable changes. So: myRandomArray is gonna generate a array by default, but when i invoke the function generateNewArray() i would like the value of my variable to change as well. Do you know how to do it? Thank you for the support.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what it is you want. Can you add some example code to your question showing which sequence of function invocations and values you'd like?